# How to detect C++ compiler with macro in Xcode?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macros, objective-c++

I'm mixing Objective-C (*.m) and Objective-C++ (*.mm) source files in an iOS project.
When I import a C++ header file in a *.m file how can I exclude the C++-specific code in the header file? I want to use a compiler macro, something like:

```
// SomeClass.h - a file I want to import in C++ and Objectice-C classes

#if CPLUSPLUS
#import "CPlusPlusLibrary.h"
#endif 

@interface SomeClass : BaseClass
{

#if CPLUSPLUS
  CPlusPlusClass* variable;
#endif    

}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C++ is a viral thing that you can't really stop. Your current example gives different parts of your code (C and C++) a different view of the layout of your class, and while I do think it would still work, I'm pretty sure this isn't a very good thing.

When working on ObjC projects interacting with C++, I usually try to avoid having C++ references in my header files. This makes the header file valid for both Objective-C and Objective-C++. If I can't avoid it, then I don't try to fight it (it's a lost cause); but I try to not include that ObjC++ header file in otherwise 'sane' ObjC headers, and I use the `@class` directive (`@class SomeObjCPPClass;` instead of an `#import "SomeObjCPPClass.h"` directive) instead if I need to reference the class. Then, I include the header from the implementation file, which has to be ObjC++, but at least it won't propagate from there.

**EDIT** Recent-ish (2012 and later) versions of Clang allow you to declare fields in the `@implementation` side of things. This can effectively free your header of any references to C++ and make Objective-C++ much more manageable (and less viral). To retain OP's example, you would now have:

```
// SomeClass.h - a file I want to import in C++ and Objectice-C classes

@interface SomeClass : BaseClass

// (no fields)

// (methods)

@end
```

---

```
// SomeClass.mm
#import "CPlusPlusLibrary.h"

@implementation SomeClass
{
    CPlusPlusClass* variable;
}

// (method implementations)

@end
```

This makes the SomeClass.h header safe to include in pure Objective-C files and Objective-C++ files as well.

Comment: I go a little further than this, and allow myself to forward declare C++ classes in ObjC headers as structs, so that I can include pointers to them in ObjC classes without everyone that knows the ObjC class needing to be ObjC++. Structs and classes differ only by the default visibility of members, so a forward declaration that calls something a struct which is actually a class has no ill side effects.

Comment: thank you zneak, your approach works for me but I get some warnings when I call methods on the objective-c++ object: Receiver 'SomeClass' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist

Comment: @phix23 You need to `#import` the ObjC++ header from your implementation file.

Comment: @zneak but then it won't compile because I have c++ members in the  ObjC++ header, instead I could copy the @interface with the methods I need to the implementation file (leaving out c++ stuff) to get rid of the warning

Comment: @phix23 You also need your implementation file to be Objective-C++. If you change the extension to `.mm`, everything should work. ObjC++ won't propagate any further as your interface file remains valid Objective-C.

Comment: @zneak that is what I did before asking the question

Comment: @phix23 From what I understand, you have an ObjC++ header `A.h` with an ObjC++ implementation file `A.mm`, and an ObjC header `B.h` with an ObjC++ `B.mm` implementation file. You `#import` both `A.h` and `B.h` from `B.mm`, and the compiler complains that there is C++ in `A.h` included from `B.mm`?

Comment: @zneak No everything was fine when I had the extension .mm everywhere. I was just looking for a way to compile ObjC-only source files with ObjC compiler and ObjC++ source file (have only one) with ObjC++ compiler to avoid propagation.

Comment: @phix23 If you use an ObjC++ class, you'll be going through much trouble to use it in a non-ObjC++ environment. My answer suggests that you don't fight against ObjC++ since it's basically a waste of time and that you simply use ObjC++ for every class that needs to interact with your ObjC++ class. With the method mentioned above, ObjC++ won't propagate beyond the implementation files that deal with your ObjC++ class.

Answer (score 10):

That would fail badly because an instance of SomeClass would have a different size and layout depending on whether it's compiled from a .m or a .mm file.

Here's what I would do (with added code to make it includable from .c and .cp as well):

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include "CPlusPlusLibrary.h"
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
    class CPlusPlusClass;
#else
    typedef struct CPlusPlusClass CPlusPlusClass;
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    @class AnotherObjCClass;
    @interface SomeObjCClass : NSObject
    {
        CPlusPlusClass* _variableCPP;
        AnotherObjCClass* _variableObjC;
    }
#else
    typedef struct ObjC_AnotherObjCClass AnotherObjCClass;
    typedef struct ObjC_SomeClass SomeObjCClass;
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { // Callable from C
#endif   
    void CFunctionTakingCPlusPlusClass(CPlusPlusClass* foo);
    void CFunctionTakingSomeObjCClass(SomeObjCClass* foo);      
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Note that when compiling a .mm file, both __OBJC__ and __cplusplus are defined. #include and #import are roughly equivalent in Objective-C (a superset of C-99), but you must use #include for anything visible to C/C++.

Remember that in C, a `struct foo*` with foo never defined (pointer to anonymous structure) is a perfectly valid type, so what this does is typedef "other language classes" as anonymous structs which you can pass around by pointer w/o looking at the contents.

I'll leave as an exercise how this interacts with ARC for ObjC instance variables. (There might be dragons and/or you may need __unsafe_unretained)

IIRC, if you use the same name for the struct as the C++ class, the debugger will show the right information if it has it available. I'm not sure if that's safe for Obj-C so I used a different name.

Also, try to avoid including the C++ header (just #include it in your .mm implementation file) unless you need it for types other than the anonymous class. Alternatively, you might create a wrapper header for it that looks like the top of this file.

HTH, -Steve

Comment: Great answer. +1 for including all of the ifdef macros.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something similar and figured it was worth leaving a copy of the boiler plate lying around where I can find it again. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a predefined macro that's defined when compiling as c++: `__cplusplus` I'd guess the same is true for objective c++.